# .Vscode file does not exist

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

After I run using a g++ terminal in vscode, based on the tutorial i followed, it should pop out a file called tasks.json inside a .vscode folder. But after I run my program, no such file is created.

I just follow all the steps in (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)[image]

Anyone know where is the .vscode folder? I have tried searching on Internet, but it just say "under the .vscode folder in your root folder". I am an absolute beginner in C++, just start using visual studio code. So, how to solve this problem?

Comment: VSCode is a very advanced, complex development tool that's designed for highly skilled, experienced developers who have a wide range of domain knowledge, like the JSON configuration syntax, and familiarity with obscure compiler flags and options. It is not meant to be used for people who are just starting out learning C++ and who do not have established development experience, those people will find other development environments, like VS community edition (Windows) or emacs+make (Linux, MacOS), easier to use.

Comment: You created your source file on the desktop and didn't open a folder in VSCode. You probably wanted to start by opening a folder, preferably not on the desktop. For me in the OpenFolder dialog I create a new folder and use that folder as my workspace.

Comment: Ok, looks like vscode is not suitable for me as a beginner. i think i should change my editor to something like Clion

Comment: @Haha You can do what you want, but I wouldn't trust somebody who said VSC is harder to use than Emacs+Make lol. VSC is incredibly simple and powerful, although the official tutorials sometimes tend to be geared toward advanced users. Also, CLion and VisualStudio are incredibly advanced and powerful IDEs and stump me from time to time as well, and you may have difficulty with them or you may just find them easier. Never hurts to try new things and figure out what you like.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are a beginner, it's pretty easy to get started.

First, I would recommend installing the Microsoft C++ Extension Pack and the CMake Tools extensions.

Next, create a project directory and open the directory in Visual Studio Code. The reason you do not have a *.vscode* directory is because you don't have a working directory open, only a single file.

Following that, create your CMakeLists.txt file.

*Example CMakeLists.txt*

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(myproject)

add_executable(myproject src/main.cpp src/second.cpp)
```

You may have to initialize CMake: `cmake .` in the project directory.

Reload Visual Studio Code with that project directory open and you should see at the bottom build, run, and debug icons. It's as simple as clicking one of those buttons respectively, selecting your compiler version assuming it's configured correctly on your system, and letting it do its thing.